# iOS application reading in ECG data from healthkit instead of photoplethysmography

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

Last year I built an iOS application that reads in workouts from Healthkit. These workouts were recorded by the Apple Watch in built fitness application and gathers heart rate information using photoplethysmography (the light sensor in the watch before the ECG).

I want to get the new Apply Watch with the ECG monitor. If I record a workout in the same manner as above, will the data from the ECG still be passed into Healthkit and will my mobile application therefore be able to read the workout from Healthkit and all the relative heartrate data?

I'm hoping I don't need to perform any updates on my mobile application now that the apple watch has an ECG and not the photoplethysmography.

Does the new Apple Watch come with both photoplethysmography and the ECG or just the ECG?

Comment: You can check the specs on Apple's site, but the series 4 has an improved heart rate sensor. The ECG sensor is separate and requires the user to touch the Digital Crown while the ECG is captured. I don't believe that ECG is captured as part of a workout.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 14 and watchOS 7, you can now read an ECG sample as an [HKElectrocardiogram](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkelectrocardiogram).

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10182/?t=105

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this is helpful. However, I have one more question that I couldn't find an answer to in the documentation: What is the HKSampleType to query for HKElectrocardiograms? Or do I query for HKElectrocardiograms differently? The linked video does not show that.

Comment: @DeveloBär iOS 14 and watchOS 7 are still beta versions yet, you can't use them before Apple release theme, or you can try xcode 12 beta version yourself. Then HKElectorcadiograms will be exist inside HealthKit